# Filtrar DataGrid con TextBox en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, eventos, datagrid, filtro

Esto de WPF me esta dando dolores de cabeza con tanto chiche que hay que hacer para  algo tan simple.

Estoy intentando filtrar un DataGrid que previamente se cargan datos de una tabla de MySql como lo hacia en Forms, de esta manera:

```
DataTable direc = (DataTable)(dt_BobinasFiltros.ItemsSource);
direc.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("`Codigo` LIKE '%{0}%'", txt_filtro.Text);
```

Se ejecuta cuando el evento TextChanged del textbox se dispara haciendo que se filtre a medida que el usuario escriba en el.

Pero me encuentro con que :

> Excepción no controlada : System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' direc fue null.

Indague en internet y me encuentro con cosas como estas

[La primer respuesta con 32 votos positivos.](https://rstopup.com/filtro-de-un-datagrid-en-wpf.html)

[Aqui le dice que lo que debe hacer es hacer un select por cada vez que el texto cambie (Esta loco)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/10a35530-24c6-41c9-bb67-f21b5d898847/filtrar-en-un-datagrid-por-un-textbox-en-c-wpf?forum=wpfes)

[En este al parecer esta la maravillosa respuesta, pero lamentablemente no entiendo.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control#filtering-items-in-a-datagrid)

Antes de probar con mi método en `C#` de `Windows-Forms` probe con esto siguiendo una respuesta de los links de arriba.

```
private void FiltrarDatos()
    {

        var Obcoll = new ObservableCollection<NuevaFilaEnBobinas>();

        var _itemSourceList = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Obcoll };


        ICollectionView Itemlist = _itemSourceList.View;


        var yourCostumFilter = new Predicate<object>(item => ((NuevaFilaEnBobinas)item).BobinaNo.Contains(txt_filtro.Text));


        Itemlist.Filter = yourCostumFilter;

        dt_BobinasFiltros.ItemsSource = Itemlist; // <- Aquí marca el error.
    }
```

Y el error que recibo es este

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'La colección de elementos debe estar vacía antes de usar ItemsSource.'

**Si sirve de algo les dejo la manera que empleo para cargar los datos en el `DataGrid`** (*En resumidas cuentas hago Binding para el que no tenga ganas de leer el código*)

```
private void Agregar_ItemsEnDtBobinas()
    {
        dt_BobinasFiltros.Items.Clear();
        dt_BobinasFiltros.Items.Refresh();

        ComboBoxItem selectedItem_tipo = (ComboBoxItem)(cbox_tipo.SelectedValue);
        string tipoSeleccionado = (string)(selectedItem_tipo.Content);

        ComboBoxItem selectedItem_ubicacion = (ComboBoxItem)(cbox_ubicacion.SelectedValue);
        string ubicacionSeleccionado = "";

        //Valida si es nulo
        try
        {
            ubicacionSeleccionado = (string)(selectedItem_ubicacion.Content);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ubicacionSeleccionado = "";
        }


        if (tipoSeleccionado == "Egreso" && ubicacionSeleccionado != "Pacheco chapas")
        {
            DataTable dt_bobinas_en_PC = gral_conn.LeerDatos("*", "materiaprima_bobinas", "Ubicacion", "CMP");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt_bobinas_en_PC.Rows)
            {
                var data = new NuevaFilaEnBobinas
                {
                    Referencia = row["ValeNo"].ToString(),
                    BobinaNo = row["BobinaNo"].ToString(),
                    Codigo = row["Codigo"].ToString(),
                    Peso = row["Peso"].ToString()
                };
                dt_BobinasFiltros.Items.Add(data);
            }
        }
        else if (tipoSeleccionado == "Egreso" && ubicacionSeleccionado == "Pacheco chapas")
        {
            DataTable dt_bobinas_en_PC = gral_conn.LeerDatos("*", "bobinas en pacheco chapa");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt_bobinas_en_PC.Rows)
            {
                var data = new NuevaFilaEnBobinas
                {
                    Referencia = row["noRemito"].ToString(),
                    BobinaNo = row["Codigo SIDERAR"].ToString(),
                    Codigo = row["Codigo INTERNO"].ToString(),
                    Peso = row["Peso de bobina"].ToString()
                };
                dt_BobinasFiltros.Items.Add(data);
            }
        }
    }

class NuevaFilaEnBobinas
{
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
    public string BobinaNo { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Peso { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="dt_BobinasFiltros" Height="332" Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="{StaticResource GrisClaro}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ColumnWidth="*" Grid.RowSpan="4">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="75" x:Name="Filtro1" Header="Referencia" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Referencia}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="75" x:Name="Filtro2" Header="Bobina N°" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=BobinaNo}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="85" x:Name="Filtro3" Header="Codigo" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Codigo}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="78" x:Name="Filtro4" Header="Peso" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Peso}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: A ver, en la linea que marca error "Itemlist" es una forma de "vista" de tu colección, que puede hacer que la colección se muestre filstrada o no pero NO LA MODIFICA, solo oculta cosas, asigna como ItemSource el ObservableCollection, e "Itemlist" usalo como una puerta para modificar la forma en que se ve el contenido de la colección...

Answer (score 1):

Hay formas de hacer todo eso mucho más reducido, pero técnicamente debería funcionar, como te dije en el comentario, nada más usa la `ObservableCollection` como ItemSource, no necesitas usar la `ICollectionView` porque -aunque puede funcionar- su función es otra.

Yo filtro lo datos del siguiente modo, aunque siempre trabajo con MVVM que facilita mucho esto:

Puedes reducir lo primero juntandolo así:

```
var Obcoll = new ObservableCollection<NuevaFilaEnBobinas>();

public ICollectionView Itemlist 
{
    get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Obcoll); }
}
```

Luego en el textChanged:

```
void textChanged()
{
    Filtrar(txFiltro.Text);
}

private void Filtrar(string value)
{
    //ojo con las mayusculas y minusculas a la hora de comparar
    //opcional usar ToUpper() o ToLower()
    Itemlist.Filter = f => String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? true : (
        ((NuevaFilaEnBobinas)f).Referencia.Contains(value) || 
        ((NuevaFilaEnBobinas)f).BobinaNo.Contains(value) || 
        ((NuevaFilaEnBobinas)f).Codigo.Contains(value) || 
        ((NuevaFilaEnBobinas)f).Peso.Contains(value)
    );
    Itemlist.Refresh();
    //Acá llama tu implementación de INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

Y listo.. y para anular el filtro simplemente llamas al Filter con un string vacío:

```
Itemlist.Filter = string.Empty;
```

A ver que tal.